# Schedule planning strategy

Tags: prolog, scheduling, clpfd

I am going to attempt solving a scheduling problem with Prolog.
I have a set of requests from people in the format

```
req_id, user_id, start_date, end_date, state
```

each of these people are in one or more groups

```
group_id, user_id
```

and each group are defined by

```
group_id, loose, strict
```

where the loose and strict are integers >= 0

The initial state of each request is unknown, and can be changed to either rejected or approved.

To explain loose and strict on the groups consider the following example

```
Group A - Loose 1 - Strict 1
Group B - Loose 1 - Strict 0
Group C - Loose 0 - Strict 1
```

Given these data at any given time we need 3 people at work as 1 person can solve both A and B loose (given he is in both of those groups) and 1 person is needed for A strict and 1 person for C strict.

The date span will be limited to 5-6 weeks - never open ended searches.

Problem 1: how to I represent the available personnel at any given time so no group rules can be broken

Problem 2: how do I "force" that prolog searches for the maximum possible accept actions instead of just rejecting all requests

---

Edit

Sorry for the late followup, I hurt my leg and haven't had the time to do this.

My current code is:

```
updateGroupStrict(
    [ group(Group,N,Loose) | GroupsRest ],
    [ usergroup(User,Group) | _ ],
    User,
    [ group(Group,M,Loose) | GroupsRest ]
) :- N > 0,
    M is N - 1.

% Reduce strict helper, try next group
updateGroupStrict( [ GroupHead | GroupsRest ], UserGroups, User, [ GroupHead | UpdatedGroups ] ) :- updateGroupStrict(GroupsRest,UserGroups,User,UpdatedGroups).

% Reduce strict helper, try next usergroup
updateGroupStrict(Groups,[ _ | UserGroupTail ],User,UpdatedGroups) :- updateGroupStrict(Groups,UserGroupTail,User,UpdatedGroups).

handle(Groups, _, userrequest( _, [ request(_, accept) | _ ]), Groups).

% to reject a request, the groups should be updated in the following way
% - A strict accept should only update 1 strict group
handle(
    Groups,
    UserGroups,
    userrequest( User, [ request(_, reject) | _ ]),
    UpdatedGroups
) :- updateGroupStrict(Groups, UserGroups, User, UpdatedGroups).

% Success when all requests have been processed - meaning the list is empty, and all groups are 0,0.
planned([],_,[]).

% If a group do not have more unsatisfied then just reduce it
planned( [ group(_,0,0) | GroupsTail ], UserGroups, Requests ) :- planned( GroupsTail, UserGroups, Requests ).

% To reduce the list of requests, handle the head, and continue on the rest
planned( Groups, UserGroups, [ RequestHead | RequestTail] ) :-
    handle( Groups, UserGroups, RequestHead, UpdatedGroups ),
    planned( UpdatedGroups, UserGroups, RequestTail ).
```

The assumptions made in this code is that there is only strict rules, all requests are same length (completely overlapping), and all users have made an request.

planned([group(group1,1,0)],[usergroup(user1,group1)],[userrequest(user1,[request(request1,RequestAction1)]),userrequest(user2,[request(request2,RequestAction2)])]).

Comment: Do you have any code at all at this point?

Comment: I do not have it available before tomorrow as it is at work, but I am trying to solve the issue as a "one day" issue right now but I am thinking of representing the dates as a simple integer with first date of search as offset

Comment: You should give a more detailed example. As the question is now, it is difficult to understand all the constraints / rules involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally managed to find a solution.
Instead of all these intermediate representations I now have two

1. a list of requests where start and end date is represented as an integer offset (request(User,FirstDay,LastDay,Mode))
2. a list of groups where they represent each day with the users that can work that day in them (group(Day,Limit,[Users])

This way I am able to remove the user from a group's users when a request is approved. And just leave him if rejected. And finally just check if there is enough users in a group accordingly to the limit.